# force one page to use HTTPS and the others to use HTTP with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to force one page to always use https it is not working

The url http://www.example.com/bookings/

and the .htaccess that I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^bookings$ https://www.example.com/bookings [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What URL you're entering in browser?

Comment: http://www.example.com/bookings/?from_date=17-12-2014&to_date=18-12-2014

Comment: why was this marked down. It is a perfectly legitimate question. From the examples I have read you add the page name, nothing mentioned the / after

Comment: Not sure who voted it down. I don't downvote well drafted questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule **as your very first rule** in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^bookings/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE,NC]
```