# force single site to use https, all other http (wordpress)

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found several related questions, but non of theme seem to work, so I have to ask again:

I'm using a wordpress site and I want a single site to use https (`/kontakt/`). All other sites have to use the `http` (due to duplicate content and such).

I tried a plugin called `Wordpress HTTPS` which should do exactly that, but the plugin is outdated (3 years not updated) and also doesn't work as expected.

For this case, I thought about using the `.htaccess`. These is my htaccess-file:

My URL looks exactly like this: **http://www.example.com/kontakt/**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^kontakt/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE,NC]

# change kontaktform
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteRule  ^/kontakt https://www.example.com/kontakt/  [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/kontakt/
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$1  [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This attempt was taken from here:

[force one page to use HTTPS and the others to use HTTP with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530010/force-one-page-to-use-https-and-the-others-to-use-http-with-htaccess)

but that didn't do the trick. My problem now is:

a) the site is not redirected to https (I can confirm the htaccess is working, since i can produce 500's on demand)

b) once it is on https://, all other sides stay on that protocol (already in the link-preview)

What I actually want:

IF the site = /kontakt/ --> use https

ELSE use HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add www if missing in domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]

# if http and /kontakt/ then make it https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /kontakt/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE,NC]

# if https and NOT /kontakt/ then make it http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/kontakt/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE,NC]

# default WP rules

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I used `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable for this. THE_REQUEST variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it **doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules unlike `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable**.

Clear your browser cache before testing it and also test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled.

Comment: that leads to an infinite redirect :/ - or more like: it always ended up in index.php (or / --> example.com/ )

Comment: Thank you very much, good Sir :) Mind explaining a bit in your answer? Will mark it as "correct" regardless, but might be helpful for other :)

Comment: Glad it worked, I added inline comments above each rule.